# Interacting with an inactive window

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to interact with an inactive window? I'm trying to make a program that can maps keystrokes to audio files so that they play when the key is pressed, although I want to be able to do this even when the program is open and minimized.

Comment: I believe that javafx is not capable of catching input events (mouse and keyboard) outside a javafx window. From what I know the awt library does have these features, so you might wanna try that one out.